# Append item to array in specific location

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

What is the correct way to order json using vue2.

My data is sorted correctly server side but vue seems to re-order it. how can I either disable vue re-ordering it or how do I set the order.

My data is a series of messages and I am using a v-for to render them, but I need them to be displayed chronologically by msg_date

```
"full_thread": [
            {
                "msg_id": "119",
                "user_id": "15264",
                "admin_id": "14",
                "user_read_status": "R",
                "admin_read_status": "R",
                "msg_date": "2015-01-05 13:33:27",
                "message_title": "Item out of stock",
                "message_content": "Dear Frank,\n\nWe do apologize but the putter that you've ordered is not available until the 25th March.\n\nWould you like to wait for it or would you prefer a different model?\n\nKind regards\nFabio ",
                "order_id": "28964",
                "ref_id": "119",
                "user_type": "A",
                "message_type": "Quote/Order Enquiry"
            },
            {
                "msg_id": "126",
                "user_id": "15264",
                "admin_id": "0",
                "user_read_status": "R",
                "admin_read_status": "R",
                "msg_date": "2015-01-05 15:37:19",
                "message_title": "Item out of stock",
                "message_content": "Hi,\n\nIs there no way of getting this club sooner?\n\nBR - Frank",
                "order_id": "28964",
                "ref_id": "119",
                "user_type": "U",
                "message_type": "Quote/Order Enquiry"
            },
            {
                "msg_id": "127",
                "user_id": "15264",
                "admin_id": "14",
                "user_read_status": "R",
                "admin_read_status": "R",
                "msg_date": "2015-01-05 15:41:15",
                "message_title": "Item out of stock",
                "message_content": "Dear sir,\n\nWe can only get the 33 inch putter at the moment.\n\nKind regards\nFabio",
                "order_id": "28964",
                "ref_id": "119",
                "user_type": "A",
                "message_type": "Quote/Order Enquiry"
            },
```

Comment: I don't think vue can re-order anything unless you are using some sort of filter

Comment: How is the data being displayed now? Is the above the data you get from the server? Can't you sort on `msg_id` instead? Have you tried using the `.sort()` method?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce code that will demonstrate `v-for` re arranging elements in an array?